# ios - How get the total sum of float from a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, sum

I created a NSMutableArray which contains a lot of NSString and float

```
DataOrder *addClient = [[DataOrder alloc ] initWithName:[[DataOrder instance]product] price:[[DataOrder instance]price] taille:[[DataOrder instance]taille] suplement:[[DataOrder instance]suplement]];    
[[[ArrayBuying instance] tableau]addObject:addClient];
```

I add the object in my array "[[ArrayBuying instance] tableau]"

How can I get the total sum of the float variables ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
float total = 0;
for (DataOrder *client in [[ArrayBuying instance] tableau]) {
    total += client.price;
}

NSLog(@"total = %f", total);
```

I'm just guessing that your `DataOrder` class has a `price` property. Use what you really have.

Comment: +1, there are good reasons to use an explicit loop instead of Key-Value coding: It executes faster and the compiler can do much better error checking.

Answer (score 3):

Key-Value coding:

```
NSNumber *sum = [[[ArrayBuying instance] tableau] valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.price"];
```

gives the sum of the "price" attribute of all the objects in the array.

To make this work with your custom objects, `price` should be a *property* of `DataOrder`.

Answer (score 3):

Also if you didn't create any property/attribute, you can do like:

```
NSNumber *sum = [anArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.floatValue"];
```

or

```
float sum = [[anArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.floatValue"] floatValue];
```